# Zuul path - SpringBoot detects it although not configured

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I followed the sample from the [Spring Cloud docu](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy) and have now configured in my `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 18081
  servlet:
    context-path: /myPath/services
zuul:
  # don't add per default all services automatically to the Zuul server
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    mytest: 
      #path: /checkPath/**
      url: http://mytest.server.local/api/
```

and a configured Filter:

```
public class PreFilter extends ZuulFilter {
 
  @Override
  public String filterType() {
    return "pre";
  }
 
  @Override
  public int filterOrder() {
    return 1;
  }
 
  @Override
  public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
  }
 
  @Override
  public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
 
    System.out.println("Request Method : " + request.getMethod() + " Request URL : " + request.getRequestURL().toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```

When I test with

```
http://localhost:18081/myPath/services/mytest/test
```

I would expect that this works only if `path` is configured. If I leave it as above (uncommented) I get from ZuulPreFilter that it was hit. I wouldn't expect it since the path shouldn't be found. Is there a misunderstanding or do I miss something in my config? Why is the path hit at all because `.../checkPath2/...` won't be detected?

Comment: I found an issue related to your problem. Please have a look https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3606 .

Comment: Another issue https://github.com/iammj6/code-proj/issues/1 . Apparently, it is a bug. I have implemented Zuul proxy without service discovery and all the URIs which were not explicitly mentioned showed 404 error. I guess this is an issue with service discovery.

Comment: Well... yeah... I think the issue is related with the fact that under `routes` I have located `mytest`. I guess this is triggered although no path was hit.